# What is the future of TensorFlow V1?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I like the modeling, programming and coding style in TensorFlow V1. But after TensorFlow V2, the V1 version seems to be just as a `historic` component of TensorFlow V2.

So could anybody introduce the future of Tensorflow V1?
Will it be stopped to be maintained or even removed in the future TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

The [TensorFlow 1.15.0 release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.15.0) say:

> This is the last 1.x release for TensorFlow. We do not expect to update the 1.x branch with features, although we will issue patch releases to fix vulnerabilities for at least one year.

There have been a few bugfix releases since (now at 1.15.3), which fix security vulnerabilities, but according to the 1.15.0 release notes, V1 development has essentially ended.

---

If your code does not use `tf.contrib`, it is still possible to use v1 code in TensorFlow 2. See the [TensorFlow migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

It is not clear what the future of `tensorflow.compat.v1` is, but the symbols exported by this module often point to the same implementations as in 2.x.

Comment: Hi, @jakub, thanks for your kind comment. If I only used the TensorFlow `C++` API, then I can ignore the differences between the V1 and the V2, right? The `V1` and `V2` in `Python` are different in the high-level abstraction, but they are using the same low-level `C/C++` API, right?